# docker build exit with code 137 (out of memory)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a **Makefile** setup for building multiple images at once. However, I always face **Error: 137** (possibly memory issue) when I try to build images from scratch on **Ubuntu 16.04**. Below are log information that I get.

> Fetched 33.2 kB in 0s (96.2 kB/s)
>   Selecting previously unselected package libbz2-dev:amd64.
>   (Reading database ... 38220 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../libbz2-dev_1.0.6-5_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libbz2-dev:amd64 (1.0.6-5) ...
>   Setting up libbz2-dev:amd64 (1.0.6-5) ...
>   Reading package lists...The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get --fix-broken install  && apt-get update  && apt-get install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev  && apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev  && apt-get install -y libncursesw5-dev  && apt-get install -y tk-dev  && apt-get install -y libgdbm-dev  && apt-get install -y libc6-dev  && apt-get install -y libbz2-dev  && apt-get install -y wget' returned a non-zero code: 137
>   Makefile:144: recipe for target 'docker-base' failed
>   make: *** [docker-base] Error 1

I can simply resolve the issue by trying to build those images multiple times. If I want it to successfully build at single run, what should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're running multiple builds at a time - is that accurate? I'm curious about how large the build context is. Are you using a .dockerignore file, and how large is the directory you're sending to the docker daemon? Do the builds work one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I am running multiple builds at a time and also using .dockerignore file. The directory I sent to docker daemon is definitely larger than 20 GiB. It usually successfully builds first 4 images, and throws error at 5th image. I cannot remember the exact size of those 4 images.

Comment: Not a good thing to do a 20GB compression and decompression and then the build. So best it to have SSD server with high ram.  Or you can try `rocker` https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine.  Also look at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14080